# Show that a function is a contraction in the metric d(x,y) = |lnx - lny|.

Tags: functions, derivatives

We have a function  $f: \: (0,\infty) \rightarrow (0,\infty)$, and there is a constant $0<k<1$ s.t. $$x|f'(x)| \leq kf(x).$$
I want to show that $f$ is a contraction. Solving the differantial inequality above gives the answer

$$f(x) \leq Cx^k.$$

Let's say that $g(x)= Cx^k$. Then we get this:

$$d(g(x),g(y)) = | \ln Cx^k - \ln Cy^k | = k|lnx - lny| = kd(x,y)$$

$g$ is clearly a contraction by this definition:

A function $f$ is called a contraction if there exists a constant $K$ s.a. for all $x,y \in (0,\infty)$ we have $d(f(x),f(y) \leq Kd(x,y)$.

How can i show that $f$ is a contraction?

Answer (score 0):

The differential inequality can be expressed
$$\left|\frac{d}{dx}\ln(f(x))\right| \leq \frac{k}x$$
Now, for $x \leq y$,
\begin{align*}
\ln(f(y))-\ln(f(x))&=\int_x^y \frac{d}{dt}\ln(f(t))\ dt \\
&\leq \int_x^y\left|\frac{d}{dx}\ln(f(t))\right|\ dt\\
&\leq \int_x^y\frac{k}t\ dt = k(\ln(y)-\ln(x))
\end{align*}